# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebaysdk'

Tags: python-3.x, ebay-api

I am trying to execute the below code, but I get an error as in the title. ebaysdk was installed using pip3, then easy_install and still the error, despite all dependencies being satisfied at the installation, yet no ebaysdk.py file, please see my code below:

```
import datetime
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection

try:
    api = Connection(appid=**<mykey>**, config_file='ebay.yaml')
    response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords': 'legos'})

    assert(response.reply.ack == 'Success')
    assert(type(response.reply.timestamp) == datetime.datetime)
    assert(type(response.reply.searchResult.item) == list)

    item = response.reply.searchResult.item[0]
    assert(type(item.listingInfo.endTime) == datetime.datetime)
    assert(type(response.dict()) == dict)

except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```

I am using Python 3.6 (Anaconda), working with **timotheus'** ebaysdk - https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Apart from 3.6 I also had 3.5.2 and 2.7. Got rid of all versions and re-installed clean 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me:

I was getting this issue when I installed ebaysdk with:

```
pip3 install ebaysdk
```

After uninstalling it I again installed by using:

```
pip install ebaysdk
```

This worked fine for me

Comment: The question shows a problem that may relate to more than one pip installed in the environment. It's not a clear answer cause your purpose may have worked for you because `pip` points to the python you're using, but `pip3` didn't, and not because it worked by just using `pip` instead of `pip3`.

Comment: The problem with me was also because of multiple python version installed, This one worked for me when I uninstalled and re-installed it. (I uninstalled and reinstalled python as well)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my **Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS**.

The mistake made was to install flask using the OS package manager (apt) instead of pypi (pip or pip3).

If you are on the same environment:

```
sudo apt purge python3-flask
```

then:

```
pip install flask
```